# React Native warnings - eg "PropTypes has been moved to a separate package"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my react native project, I have got the following warnings.

```
Warning: PropTypes has been moved to a separate package. Accessing React.PropTypes is no longer supported and will be removed completely in React 16. Use the prop-types package on npm instead.

Warning: React.createClass is no longer supported. Use a plain JavaScript class instead. If you're not yet ready to migrate, create-react-class is available on npm as a drop-in replacement. 

Warning: View.propTypes has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version of ReactNative. Use ViewPropTypes instead.
```

However, I am pretty sure that I haven't done this in my project and having done a global search, it seems like instances of them are within the node-modules folder and particularly in the modules that I haven't installed myself. How should I proceed? I have attempted the following command to refactor as suggested in the documentation.

```
jscodeshift -t react-codemod/transforms/React-PropTypes-to-prop-types.js <path>
```

When I did attempt it, several node-modules became corrupted and the app wasn't able to compile. I've had to reinstall the npm modules after that so I've made no progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning happens because PropTypes is moved to a separate package - 'prop-types'. Also, React.createClass is deprecated.

The warning happens in either your app or in the packages that you use.

To remove it in your app, use

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

Convert `React.createClass` to ES6 components.

If the warning happens in the packages that you are using, intimate the concerned package owner by raising a git issue. Most packages have already made this change. So, you should just upgrade those packages. If the package is the latest, and the error persists, please raise the issue.

Comment: Is there any way to find out exactly where these warnings are happening? I have done a global search but it's still very unclear what file the warning is referring to.

Comment: when a 3rd party dep is not compatible, you are unlucky. get them to update. if a transient dep of a dep... may be time to switch. a lot of dead weight that has not been touched in a while out there. the warnings are only for `env='development'` so it won't affect your builds. also, react-native 16 will be a while still.